# Whats the difference between IAsyncEnumerable<T> vs IEnumerable<Task<T>>?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, streaming

The new C# 8.0 and dotnet core 3 has this new feature of AsyncStreams (`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`). My understanding it that it provides a way to asynchronously process items in a stream. But would I not be able to do that with `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`?

what’s the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: How would you make [`MoveNext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) to be async with `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`?

Comment: One is an enumeration that can be enumerated async (i.e. you async wait for the next element to return), the other is just an enumeration of tasks.

Comment: Can I say that async streams of c# 8 enables backpressure out of the box?

Comment: I don’t think backpressure is exactly right as this usually more about the producer being much faster than the consumer (or at least that’s how I understand backpressure). Async enumerables rather help you when the producer is much slower than the consumer, e.g. because the producer is I/O bound (like a network query), as now the program can do something else while waiting for new items to arrive.

Comment: Thanks @ckuri for the explanation. I think understand the difference very well now. In my mind I would still relate it to back-pressure. Because one key concept in backpressure enabled streams is the ability of consumer to asyncronously wait for element processing and then demand for more data. IMO similar things are made possible with dotnet async streams. Thank you again. I am very excited for this feature 

Comment: just wondering, didn't you mean Task<IEnumerable<T>> instead of IEnumerable<Task<T>> ?

Answer (score 10):

Both `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` and `IAsyncEnumerable` are used to enumerate through data or go through a list of data. Yet there is a huge difference.
`Task<IEnumerable<T>>` provides records once the data in collection is ready to send to the caller.

Whereas, `IAsyncEnumerable` provides records as they are ready, which mean it will send you record as its available rather than waiting for the whole collection to be filled up. It provides you to iterate a collection asynchronously using the yield keyword which was not possible until C# 8.0.

It’s important to understand what thread is safe and what is not safe when working with async enumerables.

Comment: Hi Hamed. The question is about `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`, not `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`.

Comment: I think he answered the more typical question :)

Answer (score 8):

With a return type of IEnumerable<Task> you would return a blocking enumerator though the individual results are non-blocking.

With IAsyncEnumerable the enumerator itself is non-blocking, providing more flexibility for the source of the enumerable to go async.